# Como mostrar una imagen con .atlas .json y .png

Tags: javascript, html, api

estoy intentando mostrar una imagen desde javascript. La imagen esta en un objeto que se llama figure que contiene 3 elementos, uno .atlas, otro .json y otro .png.

[image: Imagen del objeto]

El PNG contiene las partes del "Axie" y los otros archivos por lo que vi tienen las propiedades y posiciones para formar la imagen de forma correcta. Como podria mostrar la imagen "ordenada"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues lo que quieres es bastante complicado, ya que no es una imagen, sino que es un a plantilla por asi decirlo, de imagenes para generar una animacion en canvas

Existe una libreria que te permite usar esa información

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Referencias:
https://github.com/freakitties/freakitties.github.io/tree/master/axie/pixi

EJEMPLOS:
https://freakitties.github.io/axie/pixi/images.html

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, me fue de mucha ayuda.